# Listing builtin functions and methods (Python)

Tags: python, module, introspection, inspect

I have came up with this:

```
[a for a in dir(__builtins__) if str(type(getattr(__builtins__,a))) == "<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>"]
```

I know its ugly. Can you show me a better/more pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 6):

There is the [`inspect` module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html):

```
import inspect

filter(inspect.isbuiltin, (member for name, member in inspect.getmembers(__builtins__)))
```

Edit: reading the documentation a little more closely, I came up with this variant that doesn't use `__getattr__`

```
import inspect

members = (member for name, member in inspect.getmembers(__builtins__))
filter(inspect.isbuiltin, members)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation without getattr:

```
import inspect
[n.__name__ for n in __builtins__.__dict__.values() if inspect.isbuiltin(n)]
```

And if you want the actual function pointers:

```
import inspect
[n for n in __builtins__.__dict__.values() if inspect.isbuiltin(n)]
```